# Call controller $scope methods from nested directives

Tags: javascript, mvvm, angularjs

I have the following directives:

Directive 1

```
app.directive('tableDiv', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/table-div/table-div.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            table: '=',
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        },
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    }
});
```

Directive 1 template:

```
    <div data-table-div-row value="row" sizes="table.tbody.sizes" ng-repeat="row in table.tbody.values">
</div>
```

Directive 2:

```
app.directive('tableDivRow', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/table-div/table-div-row.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {value: '=', sizes: '='},
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.showInfo = function () {
                $scope.visible = true;
            };

            $scope.hideInfo = function () {
                $scope.visible = false;
            };

            $scope.hasTemplate = function() {
                return ($scope.value.template ? true : false);
            }

        },
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return scope.visible;
            }, function (value) {
                if (value === true) {
                    $(element).find('div.table-row').addClass('open');
                    $(element).find('div.table-row.edit').removeClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $(element).find('div.table-row').removeClass('open');
                    $(element).find('div.table-row.edit').addClass('hidden');

                }
            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

Directive 2 template:

```
<div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="table-row clearfix">
        <div class="{{sizes.first}} first">{{value.display.first}}</div>
        <div ng-repeat="cell in value.display.cells" class="{{sizes.cells[$index]}}">{{cell}}</div>
        <div class="{{sizes.last}} last regular">
            <div ng-switch on="value.display.last">
                <div ng-switch-when="%editbutton%">
                    <div class="show-info closed" ng-click="showInfo()"></div>
                </div>
                <div ng-switch-default>
                    {{value.display.last}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="hasTemplate()">
    <ng-include src="value.template"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Inside the second directive template I'm including a dynamic template based on the controller $scope model. Inside that template and in the directive template I want to call a function from the controller $scope. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems it's in the docs and it wasn't clear enough for me. Inside the directive declaration I needed to add: `method: '&'`

```
    scope: {
        table: '=',
        method: '&'
    },
```

and inside the template where I call the directive, the `method` html attribute MUST HAVE `()` at the end:

```
<div data-table-div-row method="method()" value="row" sizes="table.tbody.sizes" ng-repeat="row in table.tbody.values"></div>
```

In this way the method can be passed down to the second directive.

Comment: Now I have a problem. Inside the second directive's controller I'm calling the function with some random value as argument: `$scope.expandCallback && $scope.expandCallback("text");` but the argument doesn't get passed on to the controller scope method. A `console.log(arguments)` outputs an empty array.

Comment: Try passing `{message: "text"}`

Answer (score 0):

A child scope is created for `<ng-include src="value.template"></ng-include>`, which means that the parent functions should be available in this template. In other words, you shouldnt have to do anything and it'll work - see this simple example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Es2UL09ASPSTa5Fstzjf?p=preview

Comment: Yes, that's true. My main problem is passing a reference to a function from the controller $scope down to the second directive which is nested inside the first one.

Answer (score 0):

As @Direvius propose, to call a method in the controller scope from a directive you must call the method passing an object with the parameter rather the parameter itself :

```
scope.method({message : "text"});
```

So, to call a controller method from the nested directive you must to wrap the parameter inside n objects :

```
scope.method({message : {message : "text"}});
```

Don't forget to declare "message" as argument in the nested directive template and the outer-directive declaration in your html :

```
<outer-directive outer-method-arg="method(message)"></outer-directive>
```

also in your outer template :

```
<inner-directive inner-method-arg="method(message)"></inner-directive>
```